# Rotating an image using css without moving around a circle

Tags: html, css

I have an image of wind-turbine I want to rotate it. The below code will do the job, however the wind-turbine rotating around a circle. How can I make it to rotate itself not around a circle? Any suggestion please

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .rotate { 
      animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
    }
    @keyframes rotation {
      from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="./blackwindturbine.png" class="rotate" width="200" height="200" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the `\`` in `\`rotation`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the wind-turbine rotating around a circle". When your code is run, it looks like the image is rotating about its center. Could it be that the turbine in the image is not correctly centered? That would cause it to appear to have a non-zero rotation radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour for a rotation transformation is to rotate the element around its center. You can change this by setting the `transform-origin` property.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

You should find the coordinates of the rotational center in an image editor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .rotate { 
      animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
      transform-origin: 50% 63.67%; // (vertical center) / (image height) * 100 = (percentage)
    }
    @keyframes rotation {
      from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-3/512/rotor-512.png" class="rotate" width="200" height="200" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked:)